# Parse a decimal from an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, tuples

**My code/project**: I'm learning Python and trying to create a pace calculator for some marathon training.

**My problem**: How do I separate/parse the decimal from the final number calculated?

**Example**: Using the following input values 
    `#[Minutes, Seconds, Distance in miles]
     [17, 37, 3.1]
    #17 * 60 = 1020; 1020 + 37 = 1057; 1057/3.1 = 340.96`

the entire code would give me an answer of 340.96 seconds. If I divide that by 60 to find out the exact Minutes/seconds; the answer becomes 5.68.

I need to take that ".68" and multiply it by 60 to get actual seconds because it represents 68% of a minute.

```
recordMinutes = int(input("What is your total minutes? "))

for steps in range(1):
    converted = recordMinutes * 60
recordSeconds = int(input("What is your total seconds leftover? "))

for steps in range(1):
    combined = converted + recordSeconds

distance = float(input("What is the distance? "))
paceRaw = combined/distance
paceBasic = (paceRaw/60)

#This is where I would multiply the ".68" by 60
pace = (#decimal remainder * 60) + #whole number
print ("You need to run %d per mile " % pace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good practice for you as the beginner would be to do this without any libraries or methods:

```
>>> s = 5.68
>>> s = s*100
568.0
>>> s = s%100
68.0
>>> s/100
0.68
```

Comment: I agree, thank you! Obviously I want to be a "lazy" programmer but I am finding that I learn better by deconstructing each step.

Comment: sure, glad to help you. Please also consider marking this answer as helpful to close the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Use `divmod`.

```
>>> divmod(340.96, 60)
(5.0, 40.95999999999998)
```

Comment: how would I grab that 40.95 or add those two integers together to then be printed with a string?

Comment: @adamcasey - It's a tuple, so access it as normal.